# Django executes the same query 5 times when QuerySet is passed to a context processor

Tags: python, django, optimization, django-queryset

I have this QuerySet:

```
brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, shortcut=shortcut)
ads = Ad.objects.filter(mod__submodel__model__brand = brand).values('id')
```

But for some reason django executes the same query 5 times (number of queries does not depend on numbers of rows). Here is it:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "catalog_ad" INNER JOIN "catalog_mod" ON ("catalog_ad"."mod_id" = "catalog_mod"."id") INNER JOIN "catalog_submodel" ON ("catalog_mod"."submodel_id" = "catalog_submodel"."id") INNER JOIN "catalog_model" ON ("catalog_submodel"."model_id" = "catalog_model"."id") WHERE "catalog_model"."brand_id" = 1 LIMIT 21
```

So why does django execute the same query 5 times?

**UPDATE:** this only happens when I pass `ads` to context processor like this:

```
return render(request, 'cat.html', {ads:ads})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a very silly problem. This only happens when django can't find required template and `DEBUG` is set to `true`.